# Literal Exclamation Mark in Vim syntax definition file

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

How can I write literal Exclamation Mark either as Keyword or Match in my own Vim syntax highlighting definition file(.vim)?

```
syn keyword aaaPos aaa
syn keyword aaaNeg !aaa
```

I want to define separately "!aaa" and "aaa".
When I write definition !aaa, it is overwritten by aaa.

I tried \!aaa, tried match [!]aaa, [\!]aaa
still doesn't work.

I read this file but cannot find example for exclamation mark. Thank you.
http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#pattern

Comment: Is `!` included in your syntax `iskeyword` setting?

Answer (score 1):

From Vim's reference manual:

> 7. Syntax patterns
>
> In the syntax commands, a pattern must be surrounded by two identical
> characters.  This is like it works for the ":s" command.  The most common to
> use is the double quote.

Most likely, you need to enclose the searching patterns in double quotes like:

```
syn keyword aaaPos "aaa"
syn keyword aaaNeg "!aaa"
```